# How to do Ping Test of devices from csv list with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ping

I am trying to import a csv file that has hostnames and do ping test for such ~100 devices.

CSV1:

```
Hostname  
abc  
bcd  
efg  
.  
.  
and so on
```

I want to do ping test and write the ping status whether it is UP or Down in the output csv file along with the corresponding hostnames.

Something like this:

Output:

```
Hostname  Ping Status  
abc  UP  
bcd  DOWN  
efg  DOWN  
.  .  
.  .  
and so on
```

I have tried my best to lookup on the internet and SO, but found no luck. I am very new to python and I am still in the learning stages. Please help!!

```
import os
import csv

with open('CSV1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

hosts = [row['CI_Name'] for row in rows]
statuses = [row['Status'] for row in rows]

for row in rows:
    #ping hosts
    hostname = row['CI_Name']
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
    print ("[DEBUG]", response)
    if response == 0:
        print (hostname, 'is up')
        row['Status'] = 'Up'
    else:
        print (hostname, 'is down')
        row['Status'] = 'Down'

#write results
with open("Output Final.csv", "w") as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
```

I am getting the output in Python console, and it is displaying the same details of ping that we get when done from 'CMD'. but my output csv file goes untouched.

This is much finished version of the code; although i am still working on it to print the ip address of those devices and get the headers correct when writing it to the csv file.

```
import socket
import os
import csv
name = {}
CI = {}
hostname = {}
status = {}
with open('Output1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)

    for rows in reader:
        CI = rows['CI_Name']
        name = socket.getfqdn(CI)
        data = name
        hostname = rows['CI_Name']
        response = os.system('ping -n 2 ' + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            status = 'Up'
        else:
            status = 'Down'
        with open('Output Final.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
            output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
            output.writerow([hostname] + [data] + [status])
```

Comment: .writerows writes an iterable. Have you tried `writer.writerows(rows)`

Comment: Yes I did, I edited just now. That is what i am doing.  it still doesn't show any output on the csv file

Comment: your sending `[row]` to the method, did you try sending `rows`

Comment: Yes, I did just now. It is giving the output on the csv. But all the output is printed on the first row
OrderedDict([('CI_Name', 'abc1'), ('', ''), ('Status', 'Up')])
OrderedDict([('CI_Name', 'bcd2'), ('', ''), ('Status', 'Up')])

Comment: maybe try `for row in rows: writer.writerow(row)` https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow

Comment: No output in the csv file :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172540/discussion-between-karan-m-and-wamadahama).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the whole code:

Note: I am integrating nslookup, ping test and ip address in this script to write FQDN, PING TEST and IP ADDRESS by passing in a list of devices that I have in my csv file

```
import socket
import os
import csv
import subprocess
name = {}
CI = {}
hostname = {}
status = {}
with open('Output1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)

    for rows in reader:
        CI = rows['CI_Name']
        try:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(CI)
        except socket.error:
            pass
        name = socket.getfqdn(CI)
        data = name

        hostname = rows['CI_Name']
        response = subprocess.Popen(['ping.exe',hostname], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        response = response.decode()
        print(response)
        if 'bytes=32' in response:
            status = 'Up'
        elif 'destination host unreachable' in response:
            status = 'Unreachable'
        else:
            status = 'Down'
        if status == 'Down':
            ip = 'Not Found'
        with open('Output Final.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
            output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
            output.writerow([hostname] + [data] + [status] + [ip])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#write results
with open("Output Final.csv", "w", newline='') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    writer.writerow(["CI_NAME","Status"])
    for r in rows:
        writer.writerow((r['CI_Name'], r['Status']))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this code but it gives the output of CI Name through the column. I have edited few things. Here they are:

Created status dictionary and printed that in the writer.writerow([status])

status = {}

    for row in rows:
        #ping hosts
        hostname = row['CI_Name']
        response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
        print ("[DEBUG]", response)
        if response == 0:
            status = 'Up'
        else:
            status = 'Down'

writer.writerow([status])

Comment: perhaps update your code in the original post so its clear.

Comment: Sure! I am also doing nslookup to integrate fqdn value along with the ping status. so I'll be updating the whole code for that